# How do I find the middle of a 2d array?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a 2d array.

```
int[,] rooms = new int[3,5];
```

How would I find the middle most position?

Comment: How do you define "middle most position" and what have you tried doing?

Comment: What would be the middle of 2x2 array?

Comment: In the context of my problem the "rooms" will always have odd sizes so there should be a real middle position. with [3,5] logically that would be [1,2] if you round with an int.

Comment: Then where is the problem? Can you tell how `1` is related to `3` and `2` is related to `5`?

Comment: @Pyreal You should [edit] that information into your question. However, you really should define what you want to happen when the arrays have even sizes, because the code has to either handle that case, or test for and reject that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, this would return 1:

```
int[,] rooms = new int[3,5] { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
int len0 = rooms.GetLength(0);
int len1 = rooms.GetLength(1);
return rooms[len0 / 2, len1 / 2];
```

Comment: This is the functionality I was looking for, I just wasn't sure how to handle a multidimensional array. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
var middle = rooms[rooms.GetLength(0) / 2, rooms.GetLength(1) / 2]
```

But that's only going to work where they're odd. Define further behaviour required...

Comment: my plan was to keep them odd so I have a "true" middle. I just wasn't sure how to handle a multi dimensional array. I think this is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rooms.GetLength(0) / 2` and `rooms.GetLength(1) / 2` to get the first and second index of the middle position.

This was answered [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a7ddde89-35cc-4a29-9aab-ac42b8fd75fe/c-30-two-dimensional-array-length?forum=csharpgeneral).

Answer (score 1):

To find the row length

```
int rowLength = arr.length;
```

To find the column length

```
int columnLength = arr[0].length;
```

To find the middle element

```
int mid = arr[arr.length/2][arr[0].length/2];
```